# In which cases should I use destroy-method of DataSource?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-transactions

I know destroy-method is used to ask spring to call a specific method to clean up. [Source](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-init-method-and-destroy-method-example/). I am using Spring Transaction Manager in my code. I am wondering if using this attribute is useful. If yes, how can I use it? If not when is it useful?

I know that Spring automatically call that method, but when should I use that? Which parts are not handled by Spring that I would need such method?

**DataSource attribute**

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
  ...
```

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

**Service**

```
@Service
public MyServiceImpl implements MyService{

@Transactional
public void saveData(MyData data){
   ...
}

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<MyData) readData(long id){
   ...
}
}
```

**Repository**

```
@Repository
public MyReposImpl implements MyRepos{

@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory;


public void saveData(MyData data) throws HibernateException{
     sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(data);
}


public List<MyData> readData(long id) throws HibernateException{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*You* don't call `destroy`. You're telling Spring the name of the method so *it* can call the method when the bean is no longer used, i.e. needs to be destroyed. For singletons, that happens when the Spring container is stopped.

Comment: I know that it automatically call that, but when should I use that? Which parts are not handled with Spring that I would need such method? Would you give me an example?

Comment: Whenever you have a bean that needs to clean up resources.